# Meaning of "%lf" place holder

Tags: c

Here is my small program where I intently put the place holder `%lf` in the second `printf`. Why the second `printf` has the same result as the first `printf`( both `printf` 1.3).

```
int main()
{
    double f = 1.3;
    long l = 1024L;

    printf("f = %lf", f);
    printf("l = %lf", l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When weird things happen, it's probably UB.

Comment: I tested this and output gives: `f = 1.300000l = 1.299999`

Comment: These are called "format specifier", not "place holder"

Comment: @M.M. Actually they are called *conversion specifications.* Only the *f* part is the *format specifier.*

Answer (score 2):

It's [*Undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if `printf()` has format specifier mismatch. `%lf` expects a `double` but you are passing a `long int`.

[C11, 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

That said, what probably happens is that when you call `printf()` the first time, the value of `f` is passed in a floating point register or at a location in stack for double. The next time you call p`rintf()`, it reads from the *same* location due to the format specifier `%lf`. As opposed to reading from where the value of `l` is stored. If you swap the order of printf() calls, you would probably observe a different output. But this is all platform specific. Once your program invokes *undefined behaviour*, anything can happen. Basically, you can't expect it to do anything sensible and there is absolutely no guarantee about its behaviour.

Comment: not sure it is undefined; since l is defined... but there is indeed a mismatch

Comment: @ChrisMaes Undefined behavior is not related to undefined variables.

Comment: Is there any things relating to the way variable stored in memory here?

Comment: @ndakostan Not how they are stored in the main function but related to how the values are *passed* to a printf() function and how printf() retrieves those values. The exact mechanism of how variables are passed may be different on different platforms.
The bottom line, the program invokes *undefined behaviour* and you can't reason about it in any useful way.

Comment: @l3x Ok. I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a specifier mismatch. The value

```
long l = 1024L;
```

is interpreted as a double; and this happens to be approximately 1.3 (at least on your and my pc. This might be different on different architectures I think; depending on how long a "long" and a "double" are, and how they are represented internally.

As for the **meaning** of the `%lf` placeholder, you can see in the [printf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) that `%f` means: **decimal floating point**. the `l` length modifier has **no** influence on the `%f` specifier.

Conclusion: `%lf` = `%f` = **decimal floating point**

Comment: The reference you linked to is pretty sloppy (which is why many of us advise not using that site). It certainly doesn't qualify as "the printf documentation". The first table is a list of specifiers. `f` is listed as a specifier. The *modifiers* appear in a table lower down on that page (which confusingly looks like it's titled "specifiers"). `l` and `L` are possible modifiers for the specifier `f`. `L` in particular causes different behaviour than omitting `L` , even though it is still "decimal floating point".  Also, the modifier table completly fails to mention `%lf` which is correct usage.

Comment: thanks for the comment, what reference would you  suggest then? and what does %lf mean then?

Comment: `%lf` means the same as `%f`. (as opposed to your link which says that `%lf` isn't even a thing). Also, this is a C question, so C++ references are less than ideal. The library behaviour can differ in subtle ways between the two languages. The C Standard is one place you could link to (search for N1570).

Answer (score 0):

Here if you change your code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double f = 1.3;
    long l = 1024L;

    printf("f = %lf", f);
    printf("l = %lf", (float)l);
    return 0;
}
```

you will see that the output would be different. When you pass a long to be presented as double you should expect undefined behavior